# UWP - How to add metadata on image

Tags: win-universal-app, universal

Is it possible to add metadata on part of the image? 
1) Display image
2) User divides image into parts using mouse/stylus (e.g. path class) and add some details for each part
3) Is this possible? if yes, What can be used to store these details(part of image, metadata)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a  [BitmapEncoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) object to write image metadata. We can also write metadata using Windows properties or the [Windows Imaging Component (WIC) metadata query language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/ee719796.aspx).

For more information:[How to write image metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709942.aspx)
 .